# How to bound item in a grid view

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

This is a two part question, im working with a dataset and a Grid view. the dataset is populated by querying a database, after this some calculations are done and added to the dataset. once all the calculation are done the dataset is then bound to a grid view. which looks like this.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" Width="100%"  CssClass="tableText" >
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
        <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F5F7FB" />
        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6D95E1" />
        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9EBEF" />
        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4870BE" />
        <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="INV_GP" HeaderText="INV GP" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="SORG_GP" HeaderText="SORD GP" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="SRTN_GP" HeaderText="SRTN GP" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="EXPEND" HeaderText="EXPEND" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="TARGET" HeaderText="TARGET" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="PERC_OF_TARGET" HeaderText="%" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="M_PERC" HeaderText="M%" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="100NEED" HeaderText="NEED FOR 100%" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

Here is what I want to be able to do:

1. As you can see of the columns have % values but the data set just has number. How do I display a % next to the number in the gridview?
2. I want to be able to add some sort of conditional statement to be able to display the text in different colours. For example, in the m%, if any of the values is less than 50% i want the text to be shown in red.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [TemplateField](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479353.aspx) instead of a BoundField and assign a class to the content to define the colour.

**CSS**

```
<style type="text/css">
.MoreThanFifty { color: green; }
.FiftyOrLess { color: red; }
</style>
```

**ASP.NET**

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="M%">
  <ItemTemplate>
    <span class='<%# int.Parse(Eval("M_PERC").ToString()) > 50 ? "MoreThanFifty" : "FiftyOrLess"  %>'>
      <%# Eval("M_PERC") %> %
    </span>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: @mikey: Depends how hungry he is... :)

Comment: if i use TemplateField will i still be able to bind my dataset to the gridview? aslo am i correct in saying that the above code  will look at the value of M_PERC and if its more than 50 it will set its class to MoreThanFifty ?

Comment: @c11ada: Yeah, you can still bind your datasource as normal.  The above code certainly _should_ do that, yes! I don't have access to test it at the moment but the premise is correct.

Comment: slight problem, you cant apply < to the int i get the following Operator '>' cannot be applied to operands of type 'object' and 'int'

Comment: @c11ada: Sorry, it needs parsing.  Answer updated, tested and working :)

Comment: @Town iv managed to add the class to each of the fields i needed, however im having a problem with actually styling each field. im using a master page and iv put the above styles in the style.css but for some reason the style isn't being applied to the page when its loaded !? any ideas what it may be ?

Comment: @Town never mind iv managed to solve it, i had to create another stylesheet and put the custom styles in this new stylesheet.

Comment: @c11ada: Sounds like your previous stylesheet was cached.  Try Ctrl-Refresh, that should get the latest version.

Answer (score 1):

To format your numbers as percentages have a look at the [`BoundField.DataFormatString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.boundfield.dataformatstring.aspx). For example:

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="PERC_OF_TARGET" 
                HeaderText="%" 
                DataFormatString="{0:F0}%" />
```

The above format string will format the number with zero decimal places, if you need decimal places then use `{0:F2}%` which will add two decimal places.

Answer (score 0):

1) Check out "templatefield"  http://www.asp.net/data-access/tutorials/using-templatefields-in-the-gridview-control-cs

2) See above!  EDIT:  Here is a detailed example how to achieve this with templatefield:  [How to implement conditional formatting in a GridView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661670/how-to-implement-conditional-formatting-in-a-gridview)

Enjoy.