# How do I convert a BoundField to a HyperLinkField?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, hyperlink, boundfield

I have a GridView (`gv`) bound to a dataset (`ds`). `Columns[1]` is bound to a field in `ds` named `orderFilename`; `Columns[6]` is a date field.

If `Columns[6]` is null, I want `Columns[1]` to appear as text; if `Columns[6]` is not null, I want `Columns[1]` to appear as a hyperlink, with a url `~/directory/` + `orderFilename`.

I have found a couple possible solutions on the Web but none seem to do what I want.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to implement conditional formatting in a GridView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/661670/how-to-implement-conditional-formatting-in-a-gridview)

Comment: Yes, it does; sorry about that.  I looked around on the site and didn't find that one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I prefer to stay away from `BoundFields` specifically because the next guy needs to always seem to convert them to template fields anyways to do customizations.  I would recommend the following:

Use a template field with a `Literal` control for your column 1:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="File">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Literal ID="ltFilename" runat="server" 
            OnDataBinding="ltFilename_DataBinding" />
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Then implement the `OnDataBinding` for the columns control:

```
protected void ltFilename_DataBinding(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    Literal lt = (Literal)(sender);
    if (Eval("yourColumn6Field") == DBNull.Value)
    {
        // just show a text filename
        lt.Text = Eval("orderFilename").ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        // produce the link
        lt.Text = string.Format("<a href='{0}'>{1}</a>",
             ResolveUrl("~/directory/" + Eval("orderFilename").ToString()),
             Eval("orderFilename").ToString());
    }
}
```

The advantage to this is you have localized the logic directly to the control.  You can easily swap it out and change it around without affecting other parts of the grid accidently.

Comment: I'm trying to use this, but for some reason, the if statement is not reading the column field as null.  Even though it says NULL in the db when I open it using SQL Server Manager, this is ending everything to the "else" block.

Comment: @Dave Reinheimer Oops sorry Dave, you need to compare against: `DBNull.Value` not `null` :) I have updated the answer to reflect the correct compare.

Comment: Found the answer here: [link](http://www.ginktage.com/2010/06/c-4-0finding-if-the-string-contains-only-whitespace-or-null/)string.IsNullOrEmpty()...appears to be working now...just saw your comment Kelsey..I'll take a look...thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Let's say, you have added a hyperlink control in `column[1]`, If the `column[6]` is not null then you can set the `NavigateURL` property and set the URL. In this case, it will look like a hyperlink and if `column[6] is null`, then you don't need to set the URL, as it will behave like text.

Comment: you have to be careful...
It is rendered properly in IE, but in FF it shows up underlined still... so you will also need to set the style.

Answer (score 0):

Use a template column, and put two panels inside of it. One panel containing the link, and the other containing the text. Try something like this:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Panel ID="pnlLink" runat="server" Visible='<%#Eval("SomeColumn") != null%>'>
             <asp:HyperLink ... ></asp:HyperLink>
        </asp:Panel>
        <asp:Panel ID="pnlLink" runat="server" Visible='<%#Eval("SomeColumn") = null%>'>
             <%#Eval("SomeColumn")%>
        </asp:Panel>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

The other option, as @Muhammad Akhtar suggested, is to use a hyperlink regardless, and only set the URL when the DataField for Column[6] is not null.